# Selenium WebDriver not finding the WebElements

Tags: java, css, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Below script i wrote navigates to the desired URL but, its not entering the values  for username and password. Xpath and css for both the fields are correct. Any idea whats going wrong here?

```
org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class websiteClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://opensource.demo.orangehrmlive.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='txtUsername']")).sendKeys("Admin");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='txtPassword']")).sendKeys("admin");      
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btnLogin']")).click();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

with version of geckodriver 0.18 `driver.manage().window().maximize()` throws exception (actually it's a [geckodriver bug](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/820)).

After removing two lines:

```
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

code works fine for me (program successfully login to website with geckodriver).

Also make sure that you set webdriver system property (before `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`)

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", PATH_TO_GECKO_DRIVER);
```

I also tried your code without any changes for ChromeDriver and it works fine.

If you still have issue, please post your geckodriver version and exception stack trace.

Comment: Thankyou Vasily. When i updated my geckodriver version from 0.11 to 0.18, code worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

it is working fine in the Firefox 43.0 and 2.51, I guess this is issue of Firefox browser. Either use gecko driver with selenium 3.3 jars or use Firefox 43.0 and 2.51 jars of selenium

use this for if you use chrome and update your chromedriver. For Firefox you need to change setproperty values only

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\software and tools\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("http://opensource.demo.orangehrmlive.com/");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='txtUsername']")).sendKeys("Admin");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='txtPassword']")).sendKeys("admin");      
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btnLogin']")).click();

            driver.close();
```